# Is the stock Celeron D LGA 775 cooler compatible with all LGA 775 mainboards?

Tags: compatibility, cpu-cooler, lga775

Back in the day I used a desktop with Celeron D 3.2GHz on LGA 775 mainboard. It came with some stock radiator and cooler which worked OK. Later I upgraded the rig with Pentium 4 2.93 Prescott (non-HT) and reused the cooling setup.

This month I plan to buy a new mainboard+CPU combo, which most probably will consist of a G31/G33 chipset mobo and a 45nm/65nm Core 2 Duo (probably a E6750 or E7300). However, this setup will lack cooling, so I am wondering if the newer LGA 775 mainboards will accept the old, Celeron D stock radiator and cooler. Its performance should be enough (Prescotts used to have much higher TDP), I am just afraid there will be problems mounting and old cooler on newer mobos (there is quite a few years of difference.

Thanks!

Comment: Buying a new retail CPU will give you a new cooler anyway... Failing that - personally i would buy another cooler, the one you have is designed for a much older CPU (Celeron D, as opposed to a Core2). New cooler = more efficient, larger quieter fan etc :)

Comment: You may be right, though I read on the net that starting from Core architecture Intel boxed their CPUs with a little lighter cooling setups, since Core-based CPUs do not produce as much heat as the previous NetBurst-based processors.

Comment: Any reason for a C2D? You're probably better off getting a PG620 (Sandy Bridge Celeron-like) but probably faster than C2D and cheaper.

Comment: In fact I found and bought a Pentium Dual Core E5200  (Wolfdale Core 2 Duo with 1 MB of L2 cache disabled) with nForce 630i mainboard. Sandy Bridge would require new platform - RAM, optical drives (yes, I still use IDE), cooler. It's not a long term investment, so I will stick to the previous era rig I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGA_775) it should fit, though I have no first hand experience with this socket. All sockets of a certain type (LGA 775 in this case) should also have the same pins for mounting the cooler.

Comment: Unfortunately, it appeared that my the stock Pentium 4 cooling could not be used with the new mainboard, as its screws could not be attached to mobo.

Comment: Ok, it appeared the problem was that the cooling requires metal plate that is glued to the back of the old mobo. The problem was that I could not unattach this plate from the old mobo - in such case there was no screws fitting for the cooling on the new mobo.